# Different UI in Wordpress

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes, user-interface

I want to know if it's possible in WordPress to have two types of UI. In Uber, we have the driver UI and the client UI. I want to know if a plugin exists or a theme. As the role may be the UI change.

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is possible. The question is too broad to fully answer in a Q&A format like WPSE's, but roughly this is what you need:

1. Two [custom user roles](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) to base the two different UI's on. There are plugins that can do this for you.
2. A theme that changes template based on the [current user role](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203917/displaying-which-role-the-current-user-is-assigned-to). You would probably need a custom made theme to incorporate this.